# Monitor Chef server logs in Splunk

Tags: chef-infra, splunk

All,

We are ingesting our chef server logs in splunk and planning to monitor all the activities to raise an alarm and build dashboards in case any violation happens.
See at the bottom all the metrics and logs that we are planning to monitor in Splunk.
Please suggest how we can make the most of chef-Splunk integration  .

We would like like to see :

- What other metrics can we monitor with Splunk apart from the ones mentioned below.
- What kind of dashboards can we setup (to check the patterns of
  the errors , raisealerts etc).

Any information around Splunk-chef integration will be great.

Note: This is not related to chef analytics splunk app,it is related more to finding risks and raise alarms related to chef server and services health.

Metrics:

1. Log File : /var/log/opscode/opscode-erchef/requests.log.*
   Content to Check: status=50[0234]

   Only raise an alert if the error string specified(50[0234]) occurs more then 10 times in 5 minutes ?
2. Log type: ACCESS LOG
   File Name - /var/log/opscode/nginx/access.log
   Content to Check: HTTP/1.1" 50[0234]'
   Only raise an alert if the error string specified(50[0234]) occurs more then 10 times in 5 minutes ?
3. To check HA failover in the backend servers : File Name - /var/log/opscode/keepalived/cluster.log
   Content to Check: Transitioning to master
   Content to Check: dismounting /var/opt/opscode/drbd/data
   Content to Check:  0 logical volume(s) in volume group "chef" now active
   Raise an alert if any of the above conditions are met
4. To check HA failover in the backend servers : File Name - /var/log/messages
   Content to Check:Transition to MASTER STATE 
   Content to Check:Entering MASTER STATE
5. File Name - /var/opt/opscode/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@localhost*
   Content to Check: ERROR
   Content to Check: error

Raise an alert if any of the above conditions are met

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?